# Jenkins taking 20 hrs to create GIT change list for the first time

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using multi branch pipeline model. Once we create a new branch and trigger build jenkins is taking 20 hours to create changelist file. But from the second build it is creating in 20 seconds. This issue is happening with one particular repository and for others its fine.

Below is the code we are using.

```
echo "$scmVars"
            def changelogString = gitChangelog returnType: 'STRING',
            from: [type: 'COMMIT', value: scmVars.GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT],
            to: [type: 'COMMIT', value: scmVars.GIT_COMMIT],
             
            template: """
            <h1>Changelog </h1>
 
 
            {{#commits}}
            <hr />
            <ul>
            <h3>{{{messageTitle}}}</h3>
            <li><a href="https://alm.jlccorp.com/epm/#projects/acs/scm/acs.git/commit/{{hash}}">{{hash}}</a> {{authorName}} <i>{{commitTime}}</i></li>
 
            <p>
 
 
            {{#messageBodyItems}}
            <li> {{.}}</li> 
            {{/messageBodyItems}}
            </ul>
            </p>
 
 
            {{/commits}}
 
            """
            def changelist = new File("${WORKSPACE}/Changelist-${env.ReleaseNumber}.${BUILD_NUMBER}.html")
            changelist<<changelogString
```

Is the any way to figure out why this is happening and fix the issue?

Comment: Hiw big is your commit history?

Comment: our master branch is 8 years old and we create branches from it. Our first build commit history is around a 20 mb file. Its showing all the commits from last 8 years.